expired transactions using flashbots eth_sendPrivateTransaction
I'm trying to send a swap transaction using eth_sendPrivateTransaction to alchemy, which then routes it through private mempools using flashbots. But my transactions keep expiring. I have tried adding a priority tip and high gas fees, but I am still getting expired transactions.
docs from flashbots: https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-protect/additional-documentation/eth-sendPrivateTransaction
docs from alchemy: https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/eth-sendprivatetransaction?
Here is the code for creating the txn to send to flashbots. Im getting the recommended fast gwei price and the latest blocks gas price from etherscan then adding an additional 50% to it.
'''
gasPrice, latest = await get_gas_limit_estimate_eth(etherScanAPIKey)

try:
    buy_txn = contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        1,
        [spend_chain, token_to_buy],
        wallet_addy,
        2000000000  # deadline
    ).build_transaction({
        'from': wallet_addy,
        'value': value,
        'gas': int(latest * 1.5),
        'gasPrice': gasPrice,
        'nonce': nonce,
        # 'maxFeePerGas': priorityFee  
    })
    print('Got buy tx', buy_txn)
except Exception as e:
    return 0, f"failed Transaction: {str(e)}", None, None

try:
    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(buy_txn, wallet_key)
    print(signed_txn)
    txHash = await send_to_flash_bot(signed_txn.rawTransaction.hex(), trade_id, priorityFee)
    print(txHash)

    web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(txHash)
except Exception as e:
    print(f" Transaction failed. {e}")
    return 0, f'Transaction failed. {e}', None, None

'''
Here is the code im using to send the txn to alchemy. I am using alchemys eth_maxPriorityFeePerGas to grab the priority fee aswell.
'''
async def send_to_flash_bot(signedTx, tradeId, priority_fee):
maxblock = await get_max_block_number_for_next_block()

url = "https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/ALCAPIKEY"

payload = {
    "id": tradeId,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "eth_sendPrivateTransaction",
    "params": [
        {
            "tx": signedTx,
            "maxBlockNumber": maxblock,
              "preferences": {
                "fast": True,
                "priorityFee": priority_fee
            }
        }
    ]
}
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
response = response.json()
tx = response['result']
return tx

'''
